# Unexpected keyword error when running rspec test

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

All,

When running my rspec tests the script is failing before running the tests. It looks like it is expecting an "end" somewhere in the function "up_votes" but I can't see where?  Is it anything else possibly?

**Up_votes function description:**

The function is supposed to add to the array if the value of the vote is 1 and doesn't add it, if it is -1.  Once that loop is completed, then it is supposed to sum the total number of votes(up votes) in that array.

**Error output:**

```
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-  2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-  4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require':     /Users/user/code/bloccit/app/models/post.rb:63: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

**Post.rb file which contains the up_votes method:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :votes
 has_one :summary
 belongs_to :user #means the post table has the user table's primary key in it
 belongs_to :topic
 mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
 default_scope {order('created_at DESC')}

 validates :title, length: {minimum: 5},  presence: true
 validates :body,  length: {minimum: 20}, presence: true



 def markdown_title
  (render_as_markdown).render(self.title).html_safe
 end


 def markdown_body
  (render_as_markdown).render(self.body).html_safe
 end

 def up_votes
  vote_array = []
  sum = 0
    vote_array = @post.votes.value.each do |vote| unless  @post.votes.value == -1
     vote_catch = vote_array
    end 
     vote_catch.each do |vote|
     sum += vote
    end 
     sum
  end
  end
```

**Rspec test being run:**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Post do
describe "vote methods" do

before do
  @post = Post.create(title: 'Post title', body: 'Post bodies must be pretty long.')
  3.times { @post.votes.create(value: 1)}
  2.times { @post.votes.create(value: -1)}
end

describe '#up_votes' do
  it "counts the number of votes with value = 1" do
    expect(@post.up_votes ).to eq(3)
  end
end

describe '#down_votes' do
  it "counts the number of votes with values = -1" do
    expect(@post.down_votes ).to eq(2)
  end
end

describe '#points' do
  it "returns the sum of all down and up votes" do
    expect(@post.points ).to eq(1) # 3 - 2
  end
end
end
end
```

**Vote schema**

```
create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer  "value"
 t.integer  "post_id"
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Comment: The error message says that your `post.rb` model has at least 63 lines. It seems like you did not post the whole file.

Comment: That's all of it.  The other lines are commented out.  Not sure why it is saying line 63.  I'll post all of it just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may just be how you put your code here but...

```
vote_catch.each
```

is not inline with its "end". Also, the "end" of the up_votes doesn't line up with the end of the function.

EDIT:

The error is where the unless condition is pair with the #each method call.
here's an example:

```
2.2.1 :008 > x.each do |vote| unless x == -1
2.2.1 :009?>     puts vote
2.2.1 :010?>     end
2.2.1 :011?>   end
0
1
2
3
4
5
...
10
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: No that's not it.  Its hard to align the code in stack overflow.

Comment: @SaintClaire33 are you ending the whole class?

Comment: Yes. The second end after sum is ending the class.

Comment: @SaintClaire33 You need a second end for the unless statement. Pairing the unless with the block is weird.

Comment: Thanks @userFriendly that worked.  I got another error after running the tests:  1) Post vote methods #up_votes counts the number of votes with value = 1
     Failure/Error: expect(@post.up_votes ).to eq(3)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `votes' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/models/post.rb:29:in `up_votes'
     # ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:14:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: I'm trying to get the value from the votes table.

Comment: @SaintClaire33 is `@post` in the test being initialized?

Comment: Let me post the entire rspec test above.

Comment: @SaintClaire33 I can't seem to find the problem. I suggest posting a new question with the new error message. Best of luck.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing!  Okay thanks for your help again. Cheers :)